# Counting Weeks by Monday using DATEPART

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to track orders per week using this simple query, where the week starts on Monday. The issue is, while the count is correct, all the weeks are one up (week 1 is displayed as 2 etc)

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,[ORDER-DATE]) as Year, DATEPART(wk, [ORDER-DATE]) as Week, count(*) as Count from PAYMENTS
    where [ORDER-DATE] >= '2022-01-03' and [ORDER-DATE] <= '2022-01-31' 
    group by DATEPART(yyyy,[ORDER-DATE]), DATEPART(wk, [ORDER-DATE])
    order by DATEPART(yyyy,[ORDER-DATE]), DATEPART(wk, [ORDER-DATE]);
```

The output looks like this:

```
Year    Week  Count
2022    2     25
2022    3     15
2022    4     19
2022    5     31
```

Now, the first week count is correct (25 payments between January 3rd and January 9th, 2022). However it's showing that as week 2. Weirdly enough, **if I run the same query for 2019 (start date being 2019-12-30) it actually works as expected** and week 1 is displayed and accurate!

If I change the first queries date to start on "2022-01-01" instead of "2022-01-03", it shows week 1 as only being January 1st and January 2nd (weekend).

EDIT:

The desired result is like follows:

```
Year    Week  Count
2022    1     25
2022    2     15
2022    3     19
2022    4     31
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results which illustrates the problem.

Comment: Why would you type `yyyy` when you could type `year`? And why not just write `week` instead of `wk`?

Comment: @Dalek I added my desired result to the main post. Basically, Week 1 of 2022 is January 3rd to January 9th (Monday starts week). However, my output is setting Week 1 as January 1st and 2nd (Weekend, not monday). So the query output starst on week 2

Comment: Whats wrong with yyyy and wk?

Comment: We also need sample data i.e. the data that will produce those results.

Comment: yyyy and wk are documented abbreviations (aliases) for year and week, so technically there is nothing wrong with them as long as they match your intent. As a matter of style and readability, some prefer using the primary keywords from the documentation.

Comment: @DaleK I don't know how to produce those results, that's the problem. I want Week 1 to start on Monday January 3rd, 2022 and not Saturday Jan 1st, 2022. That's all

Comment: I understand, but we need to see the data you are attempting to use to produce those results, i.e. the data you are querying. (Made up of course to reproduce the issue).

Comment: There’s nothing technically wrong with `yyyy` I guess, but if you’re going to type four letters anyway, why not type four letters that spell the actual word that explains what you mean? https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: Anyway just create a calendar table if built-in week definitions don’t work for you. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Year 2022 started on a Saturday. SQL Server DATEPART() always treats January 1 as week 1. With `SET DATEFIRST 1`, Monday 2022-01-03 becomes the start of week 2.

If you don't care about weekends, perhaps you should redefine your weeks as Saturday through Friday. This can be done with `SET DATEFIRST 6`.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=115684379372cb28502ad5891950e1ba).

Comment: SET DATEFIRST 1 already sets the start of the week as Monday, I do care about weekends. I just don't consider January 1st and January 2nd as Week 1 like the query is suggesting. Week 1 of 2022 should start on Monday (January 3rd) until Sunday January 9th

Comment: The DATEPART function is operating as designed. If that doesn't suit your needs, you can always calculate an adjustment. `DATEPART(week, [ORDER-DATE]) - CASE WHEN /* year start on a weekend */ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` or define your own function.

Comment: (Sorry I missed that you already had SET DATEFIRST 1. I have edited my original answer and updated the fiddle to reflect that.)

Comment: I suppose setting datefirst as 6 basically works as I want. Thank you

Comment: Another consideration (that may not be obvious for 2022) is what you need to do when the year starts mid-week. Will you need to report the entire week together as either the last of the year-ending or the first of the year-starting? If so, you may need further customization of both your rear and week calculations.